# What mudguard should I buy?

Tags: fenders

I am looking for a mudguard to buy but cannot figure out sizing etc. I have a Fuji sportif 2.5 road bike. I am worried the one I would get wouldn't fit through the brake system or would be too wide. Do you have any advice?

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles!  You could improve your question by adding some photos of the bike so it's possible to get an idea of the clearances involved.

Comment: Maybe something that attaches to the seat post, then brake clearances in a non-issue

Comment: I would take your bike to a shop that sells lots of fenders. It's hard to beat their experience and having actual eyes on the frame and fenders on the same time

Answer (score 3):

SKS Raceblades will probably fit: https://www.sks-germany.com/en/products/raceblade-long-black/

They are specifically designed to mount around road bike rim brakes like you have.

Mounting them may require a bit of tool work, mudguards are rarely "plug and play."